# How to filter list by dictionary value in yq?

Tags: yq

I'm using https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/ . How can I filter a list of dictionaries by a particular value in a list under a particular key? In the example below I want to filter the layouts list by condition "*iso3166 list contains value 'GB'*".

##### Example

Yaml output (condensed) from `xkbcli list` with one model and three layouts

```yaml
models:
- name: pc86
  vendor: Generic
  description: Generic 86-key PC

layouts:
- layout: 'ch'
  variant: ''
  brief: 'de'
  description: German (Switzerland)
  iso639: ['deu', 'gsw']
  iso3166: ['CH']
- layout: 'gb'
  variant: 'gla'
  brief: 'gd'
  description: Scottish Gaelic
  iso639: ['eng', 'gla']
  iso3166: ['GB', 'CA']
- layout: 'gb'
  variant: 'colemak'
  brief: 'en'
  description: English (UK, Colemak)
  iso639: ['eng']
  iso3166: ['GB']
```

Desired output: the two 'GB' layouts

```yaml
- layout: 'gb'
  variant: 'gla'
  brief: 'gd'
  description: Scottish Gaelic
  iso639: ['eng', 'gla']
  iso3166: ['GB', 'CA']
- layout: 'gb'
  variant: 'colemak'
  brief: 'en'
  description: English (UK, Colemak)
  iso639: ['eng']
  iso3166: ['GB']
```

So far I've tried `yq ".layouts"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map` and `select`.

```sh
# Selects by .layout
yq '.layouts | map(select(.layout == "gb"))'

# Selects by .iso3166[]
yq '.layouts | map(select(.iso3166[] == "GB"))'
```

```yaml
- layout: 'gb'
  variant: 'gla'
  brief: 'gd'
  description: Scottish Gaelic
  iso639: ['eng', 'gla']
  iso3166: ['GB', 'CA']
- layout: 'gb'
  variant: 'colemak'
  brief: 'en'
  description: English (UK, Colemak)
  iso639: ['eng']
  iso3166: ['GB']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `select` on the `iso3166` list to see if a match for `"GB"` is present. To update the original `layouts` list back use `|=` instead of just `|`

```
yq '.layouts | map(select( .iso3166[] == "GB" ))'
```

Note: Since [4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), yq's 'eval/e' command is the default command and no longer needs to be specified.